# A basic question on base-$r$ non-terminating representation of a number

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

For $i=0,\dots,r-1$, let $A_r(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ consist of the numbers in the unit interval in whose base-$r$ expansions the digits $i_1,\dots,i_k$ nowhere appear consecutively in that order. I need to show that it is trifling( meaning it can be covered by a finite union of intervals such that the sum of the length of the intervals is less that $\epsilon$ i.e. it is a very small set.

Comment: This definition is quite non-standard, it would be better to provide an example. Let me see if I understood correctly: $A_{10}(1,2,2,3,2) \subset [0,1]$ is the set of all numbers such that in their base $10$ representation you never see a $\ldots 12232 \ldots$. Hence, $\frac{1}{3} \in A_{10}(1,2,2,3,2)$, but $0.293929338122325949394 \notin A_{10}(1,2,2,3,2)$. Is that correct?

Comment: @PedroMilet: yes.

Answer (score 1):

Your set is contained in the set of numbers whose representation to base $r^k$ does not have the "digit" $i_1\dots i_k.$ Now that set lies in the union of two intervals (all numbers whose first digit is smaller than the forbidden digit and the ones whose first digit is bigger than the forbidden digit). The sum of the length of those intervals is $(r^k-1)/r^k.$ In each of the two intervals you repeat the reasoning, so if you are using $2^n$ intervals, your total length is $((r^k-1)/r^k)^n,$ which obviously goes to $0.$

Comment: @Prasenjit: huh?

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of the first line ?